# Proxy HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, proxy, html5-video

I wanted to check what does a library do with video element I pass to it so I naively did this:

```
cosnt videoElement = new Proxy(document.querySelector('video'), {
    get(target, key) {
        const name = typeof key === 'symbol'? key.toString() : key;
        console.info(`Accessing video.${ name }`)
        return target[key];
    }
});
```

But I got an error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Is there a way to make this work?

---

EDIT: I have gained some knowledge, with it I updated my proxy as fallow:

```
cosnt videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
cosnt proxyElement = new Proxy(videoElement , {
    get(target, key) {
        if (key == '___element___') {
            return video;
        }

        const name = typeof key === 'symbol'? key.toString() : key;
        console.info(`Accessing video.${ name }`);
        const value = video[key];
        if (value instanceof Function) {
            return video[key].bind(video);
        } else {
            return video[key];
        }
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
        const name = typeof key === 'symbol'? key.toString() : key;
        console.info(`Writing video.${ name } = ${ value }`);
        video[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
});
```

It is meant for debugging, so I edited the compiled code and replaced all DOM manipulation references with `element.___element___`.

Next I found out that there seem to be problems with calling functions trough proxy, so I added the `.bind(video)` part.

And finally setting values was throwing. So I had to replace target with direct video reference (as matter of fact, I replaced all target references with video, just to be sure), that made it work... I am not sure why or how, but it did.

**Questions are:**

- Is this really how it is supposed to be? (the `document.body.contains(myProxyElement)` part)
- Setting values to video element throwing when setting inside proxy seemed weird, is it a bug? (3rd point, kinda second too, I suppose it is connected)

---

Bonus: playground

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const proxy = new Proxy(video, {
  get(target, key) {
    console.log(`Getting video.${typeof key === 'symbol'? key.toString() : key}`);
    const value = video[key];
    if (value instanceof Function) {
      return value.bind(video);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  },
  set(target, key, value) {
    console.log(`Setting video.${typeof key === 'symbol'? key.toString() : key} =`, value);
    video[key] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

proxy.muted = true;
proxy.play();
proxy.controls = true;
try {
  console.log(document.body.contains(proxy));
} catch (e) {
  console.error('DOM operation failed', e);
}
```

```css
video { max-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<video src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
```

Comment: *Setting values to video element throwing when setting inside proxy seemed weird, is it a bug?* What do you mean? What exactly is the error, and when does it occur? It doesn't seem to be throwing in the snippet (until you get to the already-mentioned `document.body.contains(proxy)` part)

Comment: in the snippet is the "most" working version I cam up with, but if you replace `video[key] = value;` with `target[key] = value;`, it will throw even thought target should be video in this case...

Comment: I can't replicate that problem on Chrome nor FF unfortunately https://jsfiddle.net/ncxabj6z/

Comment: @CertainPerformance Indeed, that is strange. I originally tested all of this while using videojs library. I assumed that since it was throwing there it would do it here too.

Comment: that fiddle link throws for me on Chrome and Firefox (latest versions)

Comment: Your `contains` check should reference the video element not the proxy. The proxy and video element will remain in sync since it's wrapping the video element but you'll want to perform the `contains` check against the DOM node itself.

Comment: shameless plug - https://github.com/dysfunc/observify. This will probably do everything you need and more. I used the video element as an example with wrapping DOM nodes. feedback is always welcome

Comment: @dysfunc but sinice the library ant to use it I don’t have control over it. I kinda think there should be experience in DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, the `Proxy` object will not get automatically casted into `Node` when calling `document.body.contains(proxy)`.

Therefore, you can i.e. set a specific key that will return the proxy's target:

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const proxy = new Proxy(video, {
    get(target, key) {
        const value = video[key];
        if (value instanceof Function) {
            return value.bind(video);
        } else if (key == 'target') {
            return target;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
        target[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
});
```

And then you can do:

```
console.log(document.body.contains(proxy.target));
```

**Edit**:

> Is this really how it is supposed to be? (the
> document.body.contains(myProxyElement) part):

Yes, I do not see any other way how to do this.

> Setting values to video element throwing when setting inside proxy
> seemed weird, is it a bug? (3rd point, kinda second too, I suppose it
> is connected):

Since I am not able to reproduce this issue, it is hard to say. Maybe try to replace `new Proxy(video, ...` with `new Proxy({}, ...` and then set the video as `proxy.video = video` (you will have to also update the logic in the `get` and `set`) and see how that behaves?

Comment: That is basically what I wrote in question. This isn't really useful.