# insertBefore proxied Element: parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, dom, proxy

I have to provide a canvas to an external script, which I can't modify. Unfortunately, I have to replace the canvas later, so I've created a simple mutable proxy. The external script however tries to execute insertBefore with my proxy object as a second argument and it somehow fails.

Reproducing the problem (got rid of the mutability to simplify it a bit):

```
var canvas = new Proxy(document.getElementById("canvas"), {
    get: function get(target, property, receiver) {
      let originalProperty = target[property]
      return typeof originalProperty === "function"
        ? originalProperty.bind(target)
        : originalProperty
    },
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
      target[property] = value
    }
  })

canvas.parentElement.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), canvas)
```

Result:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.
```

The funny part: `canvas instanceof Node` returns `true`. The `typeof canvas` returns `"object"`, but so does the `typeof document.getElementById("canvas")`.

Comment: [It's been said here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-proxies-and-reflect/) that it is not possible: "*Even if a proxy’s target is a DOM Element, for example, the proxy isn’t really an Element; so something like document.body.appendChild(proxy) will fail with a TypeError.*", There are many questions here that approach similar issues, but weirdly I couldn't find one on this case... closest would be [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075255/proxy-htmlelement). However, this is not just a [canvas] thing, here is an [MCVE]: https://jsfiddle.net/mp258oz3/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, it clarifies a bit. But I still refuse to believe, that this is not possible. The type must be _somehow_ checked - but how? Is there some kind of a hidden, magical property set inside document.createElement?

Comment: @KamilNowak Yes. `Element`s are host objects, somehow linked to the internal DOM implementation.

Comment: I don't know. That's why I only left this comment instead of an answer. There might be some hack, there may not be any. I'll leave one with more knowledge write a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution involves overloading `Node.prototype.insertBefore` and using approaches found in [How to get the target of a JavaScript Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096547/how-to-get-the-target-of-a-javascript-proxy)

In the proxy handler getter added a conditional for property `PROXY_NODE` to return the original target node.

Then in the `insertBefore` overload, check if that property is truthy and change first argument if it is

```js
const PROXY_NODE = Symbol('PROXY_NODE');

// Overload Node.prototype.insertBefore
const oldInsertBefore = Node.prototype.insertBefore;

Node.prototype.insertBefore = function(...args) {  
  if (args[0][PROXY_NODE]) {
    args[0] = args[0][PROXY_NODE];
    console.log(args[0]);
  }
  oldInsertBefore.apply(this, args)
}

// proxy handler
const handler = {
  get: (target, property, receiver) => {
    if (property === PROXY_NODE) {
      return target
    }
    return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver)
  },
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
    target[property] = value
  }
}

// Create proxy node
const proxyNode = new Proxy(document.createElement("div"), handler);
// proxy setter is working
proxyNode.textContent = 'Proxy Content';

// insert proxy node
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parentElement");
var childDiv = document.getElementById("childElement");
parentDiv.insertBefore(proxyNode, childDiv );
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <div id="childElement">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt this is a good idea. You would basically need to overwrite *each and every* DOM method that somehow deals with nodes/elements to accept proxies (as arguments or `this` argument)

Comment: @Bergi sure...only covers OP specific case. Also basically a proof of concept

Comment: Btw, instead of `myTarget` I would at least recommend using a Symbol.